How are we handling Harry's questions?
I'm under the impression Harry is generally prohibited from asking questions because of repeated low-quality contributions, but he/she is getting around the ban by creating new accounts (hence all the accounts have 1 rep). Presumably that would mean their questions are automatically deleted.
However this question has a comment from a mod and isn't deleted or closed, which is surprising. How are we handling them?

The question has been deleted. That said, mods may not realize about socks unless they are familiar with them, or someone else informing the mods (e.g. through flag).
